# How to use pkg/errors to annotate error & pretty print stack trace in golang?

Tags: go, error-handling, stack-trace

Consider the following code (https://go.dev/play/p/hDOyP3W_lqW)

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

func myError() error {
    return errors.New("failing unconditionally")
}

func myError1() error {
    return errors.Errorf("annotate with additional debug info: %+v", myError())
}

func myError2() error {
    return errors.Errorf("extra debug info: %+v", myError1())
}

func main() {
    if err := myError2(); err != nil {
        log.Printf("%+v", err)
    }
}
```

I originate the error with `errors.New` and annotate it with additional info using `errors.Errorf`.

It does what I want--record and print the stack trace & line number. However, the problem is that the output of `log.Printf("%+v", err)` is verbose and repetitive:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 extra debug info: annotate with additional debug info: failing unconditionally
main.myError
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:10
main.myError1
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:14
main.myError2
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:18
main.main
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:22
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
main.myError1
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:14
main.myError2
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:18
main.main
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:22
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
main.myError2
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:18
main.main
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:22
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
```

iiuc, `errors` package appends an additional copy of stack trace to the error every time of annotating the error, as can be seen in the below snippet

```
// repetitive (thrice) error stack
main.myError
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:10
main.myError1
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:14
main.myError2
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:18
main.main
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:22
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
main.myError1
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:14
main.myError2
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:18
main.main
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:22
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
main.myError2
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:18
main.main
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:22
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
```

My desired output is

```
// Desired output
2009/11/10 23:00:00 extra debug info: annotate with additional debug info: failing unconditionally
main.myError
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:10
main.myError1
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:14
main.myError2
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:18
main.main
    /tmp/sandbox3329712514/prog.go:22
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
```

One way to achieve that is to only use the `errors` package to originate the error and then use `fmt.Errorf` with `%+v` to add additional info in the call stack (like this https://go.dev/play/p/OrWe6KUIL_m). However, it's error-prone and hard to enforce every developer to use this pattern in a large code base. Developers have to remember to use the `errors` package to originate the error and use `fmt` properly with `%+v` `%s` to print out the stack trace.

I'm wondering if this is the desired behavior (verbose and repetitive). And is it possible to consistently use the `errors` package to annotate errors along the call stack without worrying about appending repetitive stack trace copies (e.g., the `errors` magically knows the error already has a stack trace)?

Comment: The "New", "Errorf" and "WithStack" functions all actually record the stack trace, which is why you end up with 3 stack traces.

I'm not quite sure exactly what you want as output, but you should be able to use the "Wrap" function rather than all 3 of the functions you are using now.

Comment: Thank you @GariSingh, I updated my question with my desired output. I also added a link to an updated version code that does what I want. However, that code is error-prone that I have to switch between `errors` and `fmt` & use `%+v` properly. So I'm wondering if it's possible to consistently use the errors package to annotate errors along the call stack without worrying about appending repetitive copies stack trace

Answer (score 2):

there are `v` [format specifiers](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/errors#hdr-Formatted_printing_of_errors) for printing an error.

%s  - print the error. If the error has a Cause it will be
printed recursively.

%v  – It will print only values. The field name will not be printed. This is the default way of printing a struct when using Println
(print the error  If the error has a Cause it will be printed recursively.)

%+v – It will print both field and value.
(extended format. Each Frame of the error's StackTrace will be printed in detail.)

In your case:

```
func myerror() error {
    return errors.New("failing unconditionally") // 1️⃣
}

func myerror1() error {
    return errors.Errorf("annotate with additional debug info: %+v", myerror()) // 2️⃣
}

func myerror2() error {
    return errors.WithStack(myerror1()) // 3️⃣
}
```

1️⃣ create new `error` with stack file ([errors.New](https://github.com/pkg/errors/blob/v0.9.1/errors.go#L102))

2️⃣ create new `error` with "formatted" message and this `error` stack ([errors.Errorf](https://github.com/pkg/errors/blob/v0.9.1/errors.go#L112))

3️⃣ create new `error` with this `error` stack  ([errors.WithStack](https://github.com/pkg/errors/blob/v0.9.1/errors.go#L145))

```
2022/07/13 11:42:03 annotate with additional debug info: failing unconditionally
github.com/kozmod/idea-tests/core/errors.myerror
    /Users/19798572/GolandProjects/idea-tests/core/errors/stack_test.go:10 // 1️⃣
github.com/kozmod/idea-tests/core/errors.myerror1
    /Users/19798572/GolandProjects/idea-tests/core/errors/stack_test.go:14
github.com/kozmod/idea-tests/core/errors.myerror2
    /Users/19798572/GolandProjects/idea-tests/core/errors/stack_test.go:18
github.com/kozmod/idea-tests/core/errors.TestStack.func1
    /Users/19798572/GolandProjects/idea-tests/core/errors/stack_test.go:35
testing.tRunner
    /Library/GoLang/go1.18.2.darwin-amd64/src/testing/testing.go:1439
runtime.goexit
    /Library/GoLang/go1.18.2.darwin-amd64/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
github.com/kozmod/idea-tests/core/errors.myerror1
    /Users/19798572/GolandProjects/idea-tests/core/errors/stack_test.go:14 // 2️⃣
github.com/kozmod/idea-tests/core/errors.myerror2
    /Users/19798572/GolandProjects/idea-tests/core/errors/stack_test.go:18
github.com/kozmod/idea-tests/core/errors.TestStack.func1
    /Users/19798572/GolandProjects/idea-tests/core/errors/stack_test.go:35
testing.tRunner
    /Library/GoLang/go1.18.2.darwin-amd64/src/testing/testing.go:1439
runtime.goexit
    /Library/GoLang/go1.18.2.darwin-amd64/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
github.com/kozmod/idea-tests/core/errors.myerror2
    /Users/19798572/GolandProjects/idea-tests/core/errors/stack_test.go:18 // 3️⃣
github.com/kozmod/idea-tests/core/errors.TestStack.func1
    /Users/19798572/GolandProjects/idea-tests/core/errors/stack_test.go:35
testing.tRunner
    /Library/GoLang/go1.18.2.darwin-amd64/src/testing/testing.go:1439
runtime.goexit
    /Library/GoLang/go1.18.2.darwin-amd64/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
```

1️⃣ start of the first `error` stack

2️⃣ start of the second `error` stack

3️⃣ start of the third `error` stack

You can simply create the "root" error with stack and then add message (wrap) "root" error

```
func myerror3() error {
    return errors.New("failing unconditionally")
}

func myerror4() error {
    return errors.WithMessage(myerror3(), "annotate with additional debug info")
}

func myerror5() error {
    return errors.WithMessage(myerror4(), "myerror5")
}

func main() {
    if err := myerror5(); err != nil {
        log.Printf("%+v", err)
    }
}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/N49GXOQP1Wh)</kbd>

or

```
func myError() error {
    // create error (github.com/pkg/errors + fmt) with stack (message)
    return fmt.Errorf("%+v", errors.New("failing unconditionally"))
}

func myError1() error {
    return fmt.Errorf("annotate with additional debug info: %v", myError())
}

func myError2() error {
    return fmt.Errorf("extra debug info: %v", myError1())
}

func main() {
    if err := myError2(); err != nil {
        log.Printf("%v", err)
    }
}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/vgKgSPjDe9-)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the answer! `errors.WithMessage` is good to know. Sadly, the output is not ideal

```
failing unconditionally
...10 lines of stack trace
annotate with additional debug info
myerror5
```
I updated my question with my desired output. I also added a link to an updated version code that does what I want. However, that code is error-prone that I have to switch between errors and fmt & use %+v properly. So I'm wondering if it's possible to consistently use the errors package to annotate errors along the call stack without worrying about appending repetitive copies stack trace

Comment: @Zizheng Wu - it's not possible due  `github.com/pkg/errors` implementation. The only way is to use combination `errors/fmt`   [PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/dpIOmHIEKFa) (creation first error with stack using  `errors/fmt` and wrapping one with `fmt` further)

Comment: Thank you @kozmo! I found `golang.org/x/xerrors` is more sound than `github.com/pkg/errors` and can achieve exactly what I wanted (always use `%+v` without worrying about multiple copies of stack trace): https://go.dev/play/p/cGeZCOuCJ4s

Answer (score 0):

I don't particularly like github.com/pkg/errors, so I wrote my own package with similar behavior where I can control the format of my stack.

You can find my package in github.com/go-msvc/errors and copy or change it as you like.

It does not have a errors.New(), only errors.Error() which does the same. You can change that in your copy to be consistent with the standard one (I will too).

I also wrap errors with errors.Wrapf(err, "...xxx failed..."). If you just append inside a string like you did, the formatter cannot traverse the layers.

So, when I take your main.go and change:

- New() to Error(),
- Errorf("....: %+v", err) to Wrapf(err, "..."), and
- import github.com/go-msvc/errors,
  Then it outputs this:

2022/07/14 13:35:33 main.go(18):extra debug info because main.go(14):annotate with additional debug info because main.go(10):failing unconditionally

That works for me and avoids lots of clutter in the stack.

If you want newlines, you can add that too, but I prefer my error messages in my log files not to have newlines.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/go-msvc/errors"
)

func myError() error {
    return errors.Error("failing unconditionally")
}

func myError1() error {
    return errors.Wrapf(myError(), "annotate with additional debug info")
}

func myError2() error {
    return errors.Wrapf(myError1(),"extra debug info")
}

func main() {
    if err := myError2(); err != nil {
        log.Printf("%+v", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made [a spiritual successor of `github.com/pkg/errors`](https://gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors) named `gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors` some time ago [which addresses a long list of issues](https://gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors#why-a-new-go-errors-package) `github.com/pkg/errors` has. Here are relevant two:

- My errors package records a stack trace only if the error you are wrapping does not already contain it (and there is `errors.Wrap` if you want to force recording a stack trace again).
- You can use `%w` format verb in `errors.Errorf` which wraps original error with standard Go wrapping.

You can use it as mostly drop-in replacement for `github.com/pkg/errors`. So your example above would [just work](https://go.dev/play/p/VP8E5EsV44w) by changing the import and using `%w`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"

    "gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors"
)

func myError() error {
    return errors.New("failing unconditionally")
}

func myError1() error {
    return errors.Errorf("annotate with additional debug info: %w", myError())
}

func myError2() error {
    return errors.Errorf("extra debug info: %w", myError1())
}

func main() {
    if err := myError2(); err != nil {
        log.Printf("%+v", err)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 extra debug info: annotate with additional debug info: failing unconditionally
main.myError
    /tmp/sandbox3373322165/prog.go:10
main.myError1
    /tmp/sandbox3373322165/prog.go:14
main.myError2
    /tmp/sandbox3373322165/prog.go:18
main.main
    /tmp/sandbox3373322165/prog.go:22
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/proc.go:267
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650
```